# C#/C++ redirecting stdin of another process

Tags: c#, c++

I've been solving this problem for a few days but I still can't find a solution. So, I have an .exe file with a program written in C++ (I can't change it, so consider it as a black box). It works pretty simply: in a loop STDIN reads a string, then STDOUT writes an output (just as a service). When I launch it in explorer it works fine. But when I try to launch it with redirected STDIN and STDOUT using another C# programm I get the following error: when I write data in STDIN I can't get the output from STDOUT until I close STDTIN (which is unacceptable, because I need to use this process over and over againg). Here is the code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Dir\black_box.exe");
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\Dir";

// Launch process
var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

// Write data to stdin
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Blah Blah Blah");

// This is the way it should work. But it does not.
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// Other versions of Read() does not work either
```

Meanwhile STDERR works fine.

Comment: Your .exe application sees that input is still open and thus waits more data to come.

Comment: You *might* need merely to flush (your end of) its standard input after each request.

Comment: The redirected process buffers its output, you don't see anything until either the buffer fills up to capacity and needs to be flushed or the process terminates.  You got the latter outcome by closing stdin.  You get the former by continuing to issue commands to the program through stdin so it generates more output, eventually filling its buffer.  Requires Process.BeginOutputReadLine() instead of ReadToEnd() to be useful.  If you can't fix the C++ code, adding explicit flush calls, then there is nothing you can do about it.  Contact the author for support.